# Creating UML Diagrams from Java Code in Visio

Tags: java, eclipse, programming-languages, visio, class-diagram

Is there any way to "auto-magically" create Class Diagrams from Java code?  I am open to using any eclipse plugins, or any other solutions..  I don't care how many types of data I have to import/export through to get this to happen.

Comment: Very close question to - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43344/is-there-some-tool-to-visualize-java-class-heirarchies-and-relations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visio being a Microsoft product, it doesn't recognize the Java library classes or syntax.

JUDE community edition can import and export Java 5.  It might be better suited if you're using Java.  And it's free.

Comment: JUDE Community Edition is no longer available (is not Astah), and furthermore no longer seems to support Reverse Engineering Java code :( See comparison table: http://astah.change-vision.com/en/feature/comparison-table.html. But if you can get hold of JUDE CE and it works, cool :)

Comment: I have older versions of JUDE, which do support reverse engineering of Java code.  I didn't know about the switch is Astah.  From the looks of it, I'd say that this switch is a disappointing downgrade.  Thanks for pointing it out to me.